# How to make a stop button function with a play/pause toggle and seekBar widget

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to I can stop my song in my android studio app with the MediaPlayer package. I have place my song inside the app and it plays fine when I play it and pause it too. However, when I play the song or pause the song after I pressed the stop function, it unexpectedly crash the app saying "Unfortunately, PlayPauseStop has stopped." I can be sure that is something going on in the stop function, but I am not quite sure what I need to do to stop the actual song and restart it from the beginning. Additionally, I am trying to add a seekBar that reads the length of the song duration. I am sure I need to do setDuration();, setMax();, and more. I will appreciate any helpful resource that I can use to track what I am trying to do for this. Here is my code so far, not the best:

```
package com.example.hamzeh.playpausestop; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SeekBar seek_bar;
int pause;
protected static MediaPlayer Sound;

//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Sound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.music);


}

public void onToggleClicked(View view)
{
    boolean checked = ((ToggleButton)view).isChecked();

    if (checked && !Sound.isPlaying() && Sound!=null)
    {
        Sound.start();
        //Play the song
    }
    else if (Sound.isPlaying())
    {
        Sound.pause();
        pause = Sound.getCurrentPosition();
        //Pause on the current position
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Is Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Shows a message if the music is not existing in the raw file
    }

}

public void stop(View view)
{
    Sound.release();
    Sound = null;

}
```

}

(I am trying to learn how to use Android Studio also)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you making sound = null , any specific reason??
on stop you can call rest instead

Comment: The reason sound != null is because to prevent the repetition on the song.

Answer (score 0):

Try stop method instead of release().  The release method ends the life cycle of the media player object.  Stop() method should do just fine